# Raspberry Pi does not play the videos in ascending order?

Tags: kodi

I am trying to play videos automatically when the Raspberry Pi boots. I decided to use crontab for that:

```
@reboot /storage/.config/autostart.sh
```

The `autostart.sh` file contains the following code:

```
xbmc-send -a "PlayMedia(/storage/videos/)"
```

The Raspberry Pi successfully automatically starts to play videos from `/storage/videos/` directory when it reboots.

The problem is that it plays the videos in descending order. My video files are called **1.mp4**, **2.mp4**, **3.mp4** and it plays **3.mp4** video first then **2.mp4** and finally **1.mp4**. I need to play them in ascending order.

When I try to play them manually by going to video directory and clicking to play 1.mp4 video then it play sequentially. If you know how to resolve this problem, please let me know. It is very useful to me.

Comment: Why not simply rename them?

Comment: I am not suppose to do that way. I am waiting for getting your new idea.

Comment: It might be sorting the files by date created? Since the last file is the newest it will be the first. Try and adjust the first file date by moving it or something so it gets a new modified date/created dates.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could create a smart playlist file and have xmbc play that when it starts.

Note this hasn't been tested

**videos.xsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<smartplaylist type="movies">
    <name>Movies</name>
    <match>all</match>
    <rule field="none" operator="contains"></rule>
    <order direction="ascending">filename</order>
</smartplaylist>

xbmc-send -a "PlayMedia(/storage/videos/videos.xsp)"
```

you can find more information on smartplaylists here : http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Smart_playlists#Format_of_a_smart_playlist_file

Comment: Could you please tell me the way to create a playlist. I just create a file called videos.xsp in "/storage/videos/" paste the line which you given above. but the player was not play contents.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, I haven't tried this yet, but will try this weekend and report the results. It is something that would appear within the xbmc documentation to fix your issue.